# Does the Liposuction timer pause when you're in a shop?

Tags: dead-cells

When you pick up Liposuction, it notes that it lasts for 45 seconds. Does that 45-second timer pause when you enter an area like a shop/treasure room which causes the main timer to pause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No*, unfortunately. The timer will continue while inside of a shop.

---

*I tested this by picking up Liposuction then waiting in a shop. The Liposuction ended up expiring while I was in the shop.